# How to convert JSON string to struct

Tags: json, go, struct

I have start working in golang, I am trying to parse JSON string to struct but its not working.

**JSON String:**

> dailies":[{"userAccessToken":"acessToken","uploadStartTimeInSeconds":1499744832,"uploadEndTimeInSeconds":1499744832,"callbackURL":"callbackurl"}]}

```
type pingDataFormat struct {
    userAccessToken          string
    uploadStartTimeInSeconds int
    uploadEndTimeInSeconds   int
    callbackURL              string 
}
```

Below is code which convert JSON String to structs

```
pingJSON := make(map[string][]pingDataFormat)

err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(pingData), &pingJSON)

if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Printf("\n\n json object:::: %v", pingJSON)
```

**output is:**

> json object:::: map[dailies:[{ 0 0 }]]

Here "dailies" dont have data, So do i following right approach to parse and how to get data after parse?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The fields in `pingDataFormat` need to be exported (start with a capital letter)

```
type pingDataFormat struct {
    UserAccessToken          string `json:"userAccessToken"`
    UploadStartTimeInSeconds int    `json:"uploadStartTimeInSeconds"`
    UploadEndTimeInSeconds   int    `json:"uploadEndTimeInSeconds"`
    CallbackURL              string `json:"callbackURL"`
}
```

That should solve your problem

https://play.golang.org/p/Z3yszFl01L

Comment: Thank u for your answer.

Comment: Instead of having a struct each time for converting json, you can use 

`var data map[string]interface{}
 if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &data); err != nil {
  panic(err)
 }

 fmt.Println(data)`

Here `body` is string

Comment: Can someone explain to me what the `json:"{Name}"` does on the right side?

Comment: https://www.sohamkamani.com/golang/json/ better explanation than the one provided aswell as answeres my previous question