# MSSQL JSON auto to Go struct

Tags: sql-server, go

I am attempting to use MSSQL JSON AUTO to easily go from a query to a Go Struct.  Data returned looks jsony but am having troubles converting it from a string to the known struct I want.

```
func main() {
    type LOBData struct {
        COB_ID  int     `json:"COB_ID"`
        GrossLoss   float64     `json:"GrossLoss"`
    }

    type ResultData struct {
        YearID  int     `json:"YearID"`
        EventID int     `json:"EventID"`
        Modelcode int   `json:"modelcode"`
        Industry float64    `json:"Industry"`
        LOB []LOBData       `json:"y"`
    }

    db, err := sql.Open("sqlserver", ConnString())
    checkErr(err)
    defer db.Close()

    var result string
    err = db.QueryRow(`
        SELECT i.YearID, i.EventID, i.modelcode, totalloss as Industry, y.COB_ID, y.GrossLoss
        FROM  dbo.CS_IndustryLossv8_7938 AS i INNER JOIN
        dbo.Tb_YLT AS y ON i.YearID = y.YearID AND i.EventID = y.EventID AND i.modelcode = y.Modelcode
        where YLT_DVID=25
        FOR JSON AUTO`).Scan(&result)

    fmt.Println(result)
    YLT:= ResultData{}
    //var YLT []ResultData
    err=json.Unmarshal([]byte(result), &YLT)
    checkErr(err)
    fmt.Println(YLT)
}
```

fmt.Printlin(result) prints:

```
[{"YearID":7687,"EventID":101900,"modelcode":41,"Industry":1.176648913256758e+010,"y":[{"COB_ID":5,"GrossLoss":6.729697615695682e+003}]},.....
```

but fmt.Println(YLT) returns:

```
{0 0 0 0 []}
```

I am getting an error of "unexpected end of json input".

While Go does not have a string limit, MSSQL does of 8,000 characters.  If I limit my query to top 3 rows and use `var YLT []ResultData` it works.  Anyway of doing this using MSSQL and Go or should I being using different server tech?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert JSON string to struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45386644/how-to-convert-json-string-to-struct)

Comment: thanks...MSSQL string limitations causing the issue.  Not sure if possible to use this as I'd like where i can preload a sizeable data set.

Comment: why not ? : ``` err = db.QueryRow("your query").Scan(&result.YearID, &result.EventID, &result.Industry ...) ```

Comment: Your JSON is an array, but you're unmarshaling it into a struct. Looks like you have a slice of the struct commented out, which would be the correct type to unmarshal into.

Comment: Yeah, my edited II changes it to the slice of the struct.  Think I got it figured out below.  Had more to do with how MSSQL shows results in their grid versus how data is returned in a recordset.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why `FOR JSON` specifically does that, but it's not normally an issue with selecting `nvarchar(max)` columns.

Another way to get out of the issue is to assign it to a variable first:

```sql
DECLARE @j nvarchar(max) =
(
SELECT ...
FROM...
FOR JSON AUTO
);

SELECT @j;
```

Comment: This appears it should work too as it would allow the string to be 2GB (more than enough for my returned data).  Thanks!  I will put your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies...found the answer, unlike the grid output, MSSQL splits up result into multiple rows that than needs to be concatenated.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Output of the FOR JSON clause
The output of the FOR JSON clause has the following characteristics:

The result set contains a single column.

A small result set may contain a single row.
A large result set splits the long JSON string across multiple rows.
By default, SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) concatenates the results into a single row when the output setting is Results to Grid. The SSMS status bar displays the actual row count.
Other client applications may require code to recombine lengthy results into a single, valid JSON string by concatenating the contents of multiple rows. For an example of this code in a C# application, see Use FOR JSON output in a C# client app.